# What is this differential equation? Why is it here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I was riding a train near Paris and I saw this fairly detailed differential equation plastered on the wall, and I have no idea what it means or what context it gets used in. Does anyone recognize it? What does it mean? Why is it on the wall of a subway station, without any explanation?

[image: Differential equation on subway wall. Above, an overhead sign is marked with a downward arrow, a black circle with the letters "RER", a green circle with the letter "D", a green rectangle with the word "Sud" (for direction), and the words "Melun, Malesherbes" (for destinations; Sud is towards Malesherbes). The differential equation is transcribed below.]

Apologies for the image quality—I have also included a transcription:

$$
C'_p = C_p \left[1 + \frac{L}{C_p} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \left(\frac{0.622 he,(T)}{p - he,(T)}\right)\right],
$$

EDIT: I understand now this equation has something to do with global warming, but not what it means on its own, or what it implies about global warming. I'm also curious about who put it up (or rather, who convinced the city of Paris to put it up) and why they thought this would specifically be a good idea.

Comment: [Global warming equation in Paris metro](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmathematicswithoutapologies.wordpress.com%2F2016%2F01%2F14%2Fglobal-warming-equations-in-the-paris-metro%2Fcomment-page-1%2F&psig=AOvVaw2Bh0r3GsCr3DQid5EQyiaB&ust=1614785056110000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwi3tcSe9ZHvAhVUuKQKHR7PDr4Qr4kDegQIARAz)

Comment: Liam Gillick. artwork...It has something to do with climate change. It seems these equations are taken from Syukuro Manabe, 's work on climate change

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQoa-DS3LDo&feature=emb_logo

Comment: This paper by Manabe and Wetherhald may have been the one Gillick was referencing with this particular equation: https://climate-dynamics.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/manabe67.pdf

Comment: Yeah, they put those equations in various train and metro stations in Paris a few years ago. They could have typeset them in LaTeX at least! They look terrible. :-)

Comment: This is an ordinary equation and there are typos: "$he,$" should be "$h\,e_s$". Pity that this was copied by a mathematical illiterate.